# How to save form data in rails dynamically

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms

I have a form that users enter data in, with a button to save the data.  The form also has buttons to send the user to other forms to enter more info.

```
<%= form_with(model: [order_header], local: true) do |f| %>
    <%= render "shared/errors", object: order_header %>
    <%= f.hidden_field(:customer_id, value: @customer.id) %>
    <%= f.label :status %>
    <%= f.select(:status, [['Quote', 1], ['Order', 3], ['Invoice', 5]]) %>
    <%= f.label :customer_purchase_order %>
    <%= f.text_field :customer_po %>
    <h4>Lines</h4>
    <table cellpadding=10>
      <% @orderlines = order_header.order_lines %>
      <% @orderlines.each do |line| %>
        <tr>
        <td><%= line.line_type %></td>
        <td><%= line.description %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_design_item_path(line.design_item_number), class: "inline_button" %></td>
      <% end %>
        </tr>
   </table>
  <section class="button-bar">
    <%= f.submit "Save", class: "button"  %>  
  </section>
<% end %>
```

If the user hits an 'Edit' button, before hitting the 'Save' button, the data entered on the main form is lost.  Is there a way to automatically save the data on the main form before calling the other form via the edit button?

Comment: 1) make the edit a modal and use ajax to update the edit while staying on the form, or 2) change the edit to a submit and have it redirect to the edit form after saving the main form

Comment: Great idea, thanks!